# How to select video connector between laptop and external monitor?

Tags: hdmi, dvi, external-display, displayport

I want to connect a Lenovo [ThinkPad X1 Carbon](http://shop.lenovo.com/ca/en/laptops/thinkpad/x-series/x1-carbon/) laptop to a [Dell 2408 WFP](http://www.cnet.com/products/dell-ultrasharp-2408wfp/) external monitor. The ThinkPad laptop has a 14.0" WQHD (2560x1440) onboard display. It has Mini-DP and HDMI ports, and via a [ThinkPad OneLink Pro Dock](http://shop.lenovo.com/ca/en/itemdetails/4X10E52935/460/6D501EE899104FF9A362D739642CFC27) has DVI-I and DP ports. The Dell monitor has 1920 x 1200 resolution and accepts all of Display Port, HDMI and DVI.

How should I select the optimal video connector, DP, HDMI or DVI?

So far I've tried DVI via the dock and that seems fine, I can extend the displays and each runs at maximum (optimal) resolution.

However I'm not clear if there would be any technical or aesthetic advantage with DP or HDMI.